# Changing text and image on click of a heading

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I am currently trying to do something like when you click on a heading, the text and image would change. I am working with WordPress and I am using elementor. I have tried looking around the web but could not manage to figure out a solution. Could someone help me out? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look for 'javascript tabs'.

Comment: Please show us a code, a template or an existing markup with the heading, image and text.